# Accessing jBPM database

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

i'm trying to use REST api with jbpm console.

i'm succeeding with that.i'm able to create task for a user via console.

But when i try to access the task details in DB (`jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/runtime/task`)

All the tables including `task` table are empty.

Am i pointing to the right database.

Wht mistake i'm doing while accessing the jbpm console database.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop jBOSS
2. ant start.human.task (Creates the table for task)
3. Start Jboss and verify with jbpm-console

Answer (score 0):

But are you creating tasks? The Task table will not be populated if you don't have any process with human task running there. Are you sure that are you accessing to the same instance of the H2 database? A quick test that you can do is to install everything with MySQL and make sure that you are running both apps (the console and your app) with the same DB.

Cheers